# Regular Expression for SSN

Tags: c#, regex

I have a method in C# that says FormatSSN that takes a SSN in a string format and replaces the dashes. I mean I am expecting the SSN to be in XXX-XX-XXXX format. I want to write a regular expression that makes sure that the SSN is in the format I have mentioned.

Can anyone help me construct a regular expression??

Comment: Is a regex actually helpful here? e.g. what if the incoming string is malformed? Could it still be valid in that case? Why not simply replace dashes using string.Replace()? And then re-add them using string.SubString()?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$
```

`\d` is a digit, `{X}` is repeat the previous element `X` times.

As Dmitry pointed out in comments, adding `^` at the beginning and `$` at the end will cause the regex to only match if the entire string is a SSN.  Without those anchors strings like `abc123-45-6789xyz` would also match.

Comment: Perhaps you would like to append `'^'` at the beginning of the expression and `'$'` at the end to indicate that you expect exact match of whole string.

Comment: @F.J You might want to take Dmitry's suggestion and incorporate it into your response.

Comment: Added the anchors to my response, thanks.

Answer (score 9):

I used the simple expression in the past, but since there are some rules in the formation of SSN, I came up with something a little bit more elaborated:

```
^(?!000)(?!666)(?!9[0-9][0-9])\d{3}[- ]?(?!00)\d{2}[- ]?(?!0000)\d{4}$
```

This regex correctly excludes SSNs beginning with 666, 000 and 900-999, according to the [Social Security Number Randomization](http://www.ssa.gov/employer/randomization.html).

You can try it out at [Rubular](http://rubular.com/).

Comment: Could you expand the regex for when there are no dashes in the SSN?

Comment: or you can refer this regex tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8uCHRyK_VMo

Answer (score 3):

You can also try

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\d{9}|\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$", 
ErrorMessage = "Invalid Social Security Number")]
```