# RegEx for validating number formats

Tags: regex, linux, unix

I'm just trying to look for all lines that have this number format: "###-##-####" kind of like a social security number. 
An example:

"987-65-4321, Hadfield, Chris" is one line in the file, all lines should follow this similar format. I want to validate that the format is correct.

I'm having problems as I'm not experienced with regex. I've tried patterns that I believed would work but wouldn't

Currently I'm at `grep "^[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{4}"` which actually won't return any results. So it's ***NOT*** working for me.

Also I'm not sure why but even when I try to use `"\d"` even by itself, it will only return strings containing a literal "d" and not a digit.

Comment: [SSN Regex for 123-45-6789 OR XXX-XX-XXXX](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4087468/608639), [Regular Expression for SSN](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7067874/608639), etc. Phone numbers are similar and may be more popular: [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/123559/608639). Also see [Social Security Number | Valid SSNs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_Security_number#Valid_SSNs).

Comment: @jww The link for "Regular Expression for SSN" is in essence, the exact same regex that I have, just that ```\d``` is replaced with ```[0-9]``` range. Also for some reason ```\d``` won't work reliably for me

Comment: What about: `grep -P '\d{3}\-\d{2}\-\d{4}' file`?

Comment: @PaulT. That actually works. Thank you!

Comment: You needed `grep -E` or `egrep` for the RE in your question, btw.

Comment: @Artish - Please place answers in Answer blocks. Later, you can accept your own Answer. Also see [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/173448)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grep -P` or `grep -E` in order to factor in regular expressions.